# Android FloatingActionButton - transparent backgroundTint cause octagon side effect when pressed

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I use `com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0` and since I switched to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` I started suffering from the problems with `FloatingActionButton`

The thing is, I use custom vectors from SVG files. I apply it to `FloatingActionButton` but I can't make button container transparent. If i set `app:backgroundTint="@null"` it becomes black. If I set `app:backgroundTint="@color/transparent"` the button looks great until it pressed. On being pressed it doesn't show a circle shadow animation as usually, now it is weird octagon and I cannot get rid of it :(

[image]

Comment: It seems like it doesn't related with Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar. Got the same problem using AppCompat theme